# Proof that $f(c) = c^2$ for some $c \in (0,1)$.

Tags: real-analysis

Number 7 from [this released exam](https://math.berkeley.edu/sites/default/files/pages/F03_Final_Exam-D.Geba_.pdf):

> Let $f : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous function such that:
>   $$ \int_0^1 f(x) dx = \frac{1}{3}$$
>   Prove that $\exists c \in (0,1)$ such that $f(c) = c^2$.

So far I have considered a funciton:

$$g(x) = x^2 - f(x)$$

evaluating it at $0$ and $1$ you get the range of this function must be $[-f(0), 1 - f(1)]$. After that I am not really sure what to do but I want to show that $-f(0) \leq 0$ and $1-f(1) \geq 0$ and then use IVT.

I tried considdering cases where both $-f(0)$ and $1-f(1)$ are either both greater than or both less than $0$ and tried coming up with a contradiction, but I see no clear cut contradiction I can make.

I know that $\int_0^1 x^2 dx$ is also $\frac{1}{3}$ as well as $\int_0^1 f(x) dx = \frac{1}{3}$, but I am not sure how to apply these facts.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: Suppose $f(x)$ stayed always above or always below $x^2$. What could you say about its integral?

Comment: @IsaacSolomon: I posted an answer using your hint. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the hint that Solomon provided:

If $f(x)>x^2$ on $[0,1]$ then $\int_0^1 f(x) > \int_0^1 x^2$ but they are both equal. A similar argument goes for $f(x)<x^2$. Hence, if $f(x)=x^2$ in which case we are done, or $f(x)$ could differ. (1) So for some $k \in (0,1)$ $f(k) < k^2$ and for some $k' \in (0,1)$, $f(k') > (k')^2$ Let

$$h(x) = f(x) - x^2$$

But by (1) and IVT $h(x) = 0$ on $(0,1)$ so $f(c) = c^2$ for some $c$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\int_0^1(f(t)-t^2)dt=0$, thus MVT for integrals  implies that there exists $x\in[0,1]$ such that $(f(x)-x^2)(1-0)=\int_0^1(f(t)-t^2)dt=0$.

Comment: Thanks for the input! I cannot, however, use MVT as this was never discussed in class. Nevertheless, interesting approach!

Comment: $\int_a^bf(t)dt =(a-b)f(c), c\in [a,b]$